# Qt. Перенос данных из qtablebiew в базу данных

Tags: qt

Небольшой вопрос по реализации запроса в  базу данных. Есть qtablebiew в котором 8 столбцов и несколько десяток строк. Эти данные нужно перенести в базу данных на sqlite. Собственно вопрос. Я могу выковыривать по одной строке и делать каждый раз запрос "insert into", тем самым перенося по одной строке в бд. Но есть ли более рациональный способ. К примеру перенести всё одним запросом?

Comment: Например, можно воспользоваться моделью для работы с sql-базой: https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#details Чтобы вручную сказать модели закоммитить все изменения в таблице: https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#submitAll

Comment: А в целях ресурсов компьютера, что выгоднее использовать в данной ситуации? qsqlquery или же стоит подумать на счет qsqltablemodel?

Comment: Сначала делайте так, как удобнее. Т.е. попробуйте оба подхода и оцените их. Но, qsqltablemodel, эффективнее будет, например при коммите он, судя по описанию метода, закоммитит только те значения, что изменились, т.к. модель таблицы знает что было редактировано.

Comment: У меня сложность понимания того, как происходит выборка данных из qtableview в qsqltable model, потому что во всех гайдах данные берут из бд в tableview, а мне нужно наоборот. Не намекнете как это делается?

Comment: Нужно будет создать в базе данных вашу таблицу и модели указать ссылку на подключение к базе (QSqlDatabase, но можно не указывать если коннект будет только один) и саму таблицу через setTable (смотрите в примере https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#details)

Comment: Сначала подключите таблицу к базе, а потом накидайте те значения, которые у вас есть в таблицу